# Аутентификация Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, json, laravel

Есть приложение на laravel 5.2
В нем есть стандартная аутентификация HTTP basic.
При загрузке view начально странице я подключаю front-end на js.
Вопрос в следующем. Как я могу аутентифицировать пользователя на js не используя токены.
Хочется аутентифицировать пользователя по твой же системе http basic. 
laravel оставляет cookie, но там я ключа аутентификации не нашел.
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

При стандартной аутентификации, Laravel сохраняет в куках сессию и XSRF-токен.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-x-xsrf-token

Который проверяется в VerifyCsrfToken middleware (включен в web middleware group). Этот посредник автоматом проверяет токен из запроса и токен, который хранится в сессии.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вы дальше работаете в JS с того же домена, то токен должен пробрасываться автоматически браузером. Если этого не происходит, то нужно добавить хэдер перед запросами:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант:

```
Route::get('profile', function () {
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
})->middleware('auth.basic');
```

Второй вариант без использования кук создать свой middleware

```
namespace Illuminate\Auth\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthenticateOnceWithBasicAuth
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, $next)
{
    return Auth::onceBasic() ?: $next($request);
}

}
```

И

```
Route::get('api/user', function () {
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
})->middleware('auth.basic.once');
```

Так же вы можете указать маршруты для которых контроль токена отключен. Для этого в middleware VerifyCsrfToken нужно добавить

```
protected $except = [
    'stripe/*',
];
```